# Inequality solving as a function of other variable

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

Suppose I need to show that the following holds for any $x \in D$,
$$ Ay^2(x) + By(x) + Cx + E \geq 0, $$
but the expression becomes quite complicated when I insert $y(x)$. Is the following attempt mathematically correct, if so possibly why? (It seems to me intuitively correct.)

Attempt: Pretend (i) the left-hand side as as function of $y$, and (ii) $x$ as a parameter. Then solve for $y$ in which inequality holds (the condition will be as a function of $x$ at the end, e.g., $M_1(x) \leq y(x) \leq M_2(x)$, where $M$'s are some functions.) Then, I will prove the conditions with $M$ for any $x \in D.$

What do you think?

Comment: Tried it out?  For e.g. with $y(x)=e^x$, or even $y=x^2$?  Nothing wrong with doing this as long as you keep track of signs and conditions carefully, but it may not result in anything more tractable than the original...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to see what happens with this, and WLOG we may set $A \to 1, B \to 2B$.  Then essentially you are setting:
$$(y + B)^2 \geqslant B^2-Cx - E$$

Now if $RHS \leqslant 0$, this holds trivially for any $y(x)$, so $Cx \geqslant  B^2-E$ is part of the solution set, and this is easy to get knowing the sign of $C$.

Else, we have $z(x) = \sqrt{B^2-Cx-E} > 0$, and $(y+z+B)(y-z+B)\geqslant 0$ so you do get "boundaries" as $ y \in \Bbb R \setminus (B-z, B+z)$.

While we know $y, z$, inverting those functions and finding the remaining solution set for $x$ doesn't seem particularly easier than the original equation...